# Bootstrap Datetimepicker modal calendar position append not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I want the datepicker should visible near the **input** box. I have tried with container position. but still not working.

```
<div class="input-group  date">
    <input type="text" name="dates" class="form-control daterange" value=""/>              
</div>
<div id="CalModal"></div>
$('.daterange').daterangepicker({                    
        "locale": {
            "container": "#CalModal",
    }
});
```

[image: sample-img]

Comment: Can you create a complete working snippet same to your page?

Answer (score 1):

By default it looks like the component is working as expected.  Although I do think something in your code is causing this problem.  I was able to reproduce a similar issue where the datepicker drops down below where it should be. Take a look at this screen shot.  I disabled the `top` property on the datepicker and then it came down about 40 pixels.  Look for something in your code that is overwriting the top property.

[image: Screenshot of reproduced issue, top has been disabled in the web inspector on the element]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working as expected!

```js
$('.daterange').daterangepicker({
  "opens": "left",
  "locale": {
    "container": "#CalModal",
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Search</th>
    <th>
      <input class="form-control" />
    </th>
    <th>
      <input class="form-control" />
    </th>
    <th>
      <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" name="dates" class="form-control daterange" value="" />
      </div>
      <div id="CalModal"></div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you think its binding into the `CalModal` id?

Comment: @Saravana from the library documentation there is no such property.